# Spreadsheet formula to extract regex groups

Tags: regex, google-sheets, google-sheets-formula, grouping

I'm trying to turn this `R_A_E_M_YT_Keywords_A_47` into this `R_A_E_Keywords`

What is missing in my spreadsheet formula?

```
=REGEXREPLACE(Input!I28:I,"([A-Za-z]+)_([A-Za-z]+)_([A-Za-z]+)_([A-Za-z]+)_([A-Za-z]+)_([A-Za-z]+)_([A-Za-z]+)", "$1_$2_$3_$6")
```

Answer (score 1):

`_47` leaves there because you haven't replaced it.

`=REGEXREPLACE(Input!I28:I,"([A-Za-z]+)_([A-Za-z]+)_([A-Za-z]+)_([A-Za-z]+)_([A-Za-z]+)_([A-Za-z]+)_([A-Za-z]+).*$", "$1_$2_$3_$6")`

Answer (score 1):

A different approach:

```
=join("_", query(split(A2, "_"), "Select Col1, Col2, Col3, Col6", 0))
```

[image]